# sql запрос на вывод изменения остатка на балансе

Tags: sql

Подскажите как составить запрос, чтобы получить результат на основе таблицы tran. Сам запрос должен выводить как менялся остаток на балансе при совершении транзакций.

результат:

[image: TRANSACTION_ID CHANGE DATE TOTAL BALANCE 9002 bank 02/01/2020 122 122 9012 pay 02/05/2020 -67 55 9101 bank 02/01/2020 126 181 9111 mall 02/04/2020 -88 93 9210 bank 02/03/2020 212 305 9309 bank 02/03/2020 146 451 9408 pay 02/03/2020 -135 316 9507 transact 02/03/2020 98 414 9606 mall 02/03/2020 -57 357 9705 bank 02/02/2020 32 389 9804 mall 02/02/2020 -153 236 9903 bank 02/02/2020 244 480]

таблица tran:

[image: TRANSACTION_ID CHANGE DATE TOTAL 9101 bank 01.02.2020 126 9002 bank 01.02.2020 122 9903 bank 02.02.2020 244 9804 mall 02.02.2020 -153 9705 bank 02.02.2020 32 9606 mall 03.02.2020 -57 9507 transact 03.02.2020 98 9408 pay 03.02.2020 -135 9309 bank 03.02.2020 146 9210 bank 03.02.2020 212 9111 mall 04.02.2020 -88 9012 pay 05.02.2020 -67]

Comment: совершенно не ясна очередность событий в таблице нижней (tran) внутри одной даты

Comment: тут видимо не по дате очередность, а по transaction_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Платформа и версия СУБД не указана, поэтому предлагаю решение на MS SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #tran ([TRANSACTION_ID] INT, [CHANGE] VARCHAR(255), [DATE] DATETIME, TOTAL MONEY )

INSERT #tran ([TRANSACTION_ID], [CHANGE], [DATE], [TOTAL])
VALUES 
    (9101, 'bank', '01.02.2020', 126),
    (9002, 'bank', '01.02.2020', 122),
    (9903, 'bank', '02.02.2020', 244),
    (9804, 'mail', '02.02.2020', -153),
    (9705, 'bank', '02.02.2020', 32),
    (9606, 'mail', '03.02.2020', -57),
    (9507, 'transact', '03.02.2020', 98),
    (9408, 'pay', '03.02.2020', -135),
    (9309, 'bank', '03.02.2020', 146),
    (9210, 'bank', '03.02.2020', 212),
    (9111, 'mail', '04.02.2020', -88),
    (9012, 'pay', '05.02.2020', -67)
    
SELECT 
    *,
    BALANCE = (SELECT SUM(t2.TOTAL) FROM #tran t2 WHERE t2.TRANSACTION_ID <= t.TRANSACTION_ID) 
FROM #tran t
ORDER BY t.TRANSACTION_ID

DROP TABLE #tran
```

Как то так.